# alter box using php

Tags: php

Please help

I have web page on which there is a sign in . Once i enter the login detail and click on submit button , it goes to next page loginauthentic.php page and where it check with database and if user exit it get redirect to main page again .

Now what i want to do is once it get redirected to main page . On main page it should display message or alert box " Login in "

And alter box or message should come in front with all image on main page should be visible in background

Comment: do you have any code we can see because your explanation is not too descriptive

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand you completley, if you want to change content depending on whether a user is logged in or not, then you need to save the login status in the session then use a simple conditional to detect whether the session variable is set and echo out the correct markup.

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in']){
 echo 'something';
} else {
 echo 'something else';
}
```

However I do not know if this is even what you are asking...